# Drupal 8 merge query with addexpression?

Tags: drupal, merge

I am trying to run a query like this

```
INSERT INTO user__field_ip_address ('bundle', 'deleted', 'entity_id', 'revision_id', 'langcode', 'delta'. 'field_ip_address_ipv6', 'field_ip_address_ip_from', 'field_ip_address_ip_to') 
VALUES ($bundle, $deleted, $entity_id, $revision_id, $langcode, $delta. $field_ip_address_ipv6, UNHEX($field_ip_address_ip_from), UNHEX($field_ip_address_ip_to))
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE 'bundle'                   = $bundle,
   'field_ip_address_ipv6'    = $field_ip_address_ipv6,
   'field_ip_address_ip_from' = UNHEX($field_ip_address_ip_from),
   'field_ip_address_ip_to'   = UNHEX($field_ip_address_ip_to);
```

The only way I can see to do this is via the merge query in Drupal 8, but I do not see how I can get the mysql function UNHEX() to work with it, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is no way to do exactly what I wanted, but I can run multiple queries to get the same query.

1. run a select query to see if the record exists.
2. if it does exist, run an update
3. if it does not exist, run an insert

running this separation allows me to use the addExpression.